# Pandas datetime index ceil to specific hour in day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a datetime index which I would like to round up(ceil) to a specific hour in the day. I am already aware of pandas' offset [aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases) and how they work, but specifically I would like to tell it to round the datetime to a specific hour in the day(or a specific day in the month). For example I would like to have this kind of transformation:

```
print(results.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-12-14 05:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 06:00:00+01:00',
           '2018-12-14 07:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00',
           '2018-12-14 09:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 10:00:00+01:00',
           '2018-12-14 11:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 12:00:00+01:00',
           '2018-12-14 13:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 14:00:00+01:00',
```

Turns into

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00',
           '2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00',
           '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00',
           '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00',
           '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00',
```

As far as I'm aware, there does not exist such a parameter that we can pass to ceil() that would allow this, since we can only round to nearest hour, day, month(freq='H', 'D', 'M')...
Is there an elegant solution to this or would I have to code my own for loop?

Comment: If you just need a certain hour for each date, why not use `replace`?

Answer (score 2):

One idea is use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`offsets.DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) - here `hour` without `s` means set values to `8`, `day` with `s` means add one day to original days:

```
d = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2018-12-14 05:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 06:00:00+01:00',
                      '2018-12-14 07:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00',
                      '2018-12-14 09:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 10:00:00+01:00',
                      '2018-12-14 11:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 12:00:00+01:00',
                      '2018-12-14 13:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 14:00:00+01:00'])
           
results = pd.DataFrame(index=d)

out = np.where(results.index.hour <= 8, 
               results.index + pd.offsets.DateOffset(hour=8), 
               results.index + pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1, hour=8))

print (pd.DatetimeIndex(out))
DatetimeIndex(['2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00',
               '2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00',
               '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00',
               '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00',
               '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]', freq=None)
```

Another idea is use `Timedelta`s and add day only if condition is `True`:

```
m = results.index.hour > 8
out = results.index + pd.offsets.DateOffset(hour=8)  + pd.Timedelta(days=1) * m
print (out)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00',
               '2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00',
               '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00',
               '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00',
               '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]', freq=None)
```

---

```
m = results.index.hour > 8
out = results.index.floor('d') + pd.Timedelta(hours=8)  + pd.Timedelta(days=1) * m
print (out)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00',
               '2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-14 08:00:00+01:00',
               '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00',
               '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00',
               '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00', '2018-12-15 08:00:00+01:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]', freq=None)
```

Comment: @MrFuppes - I see.

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, I didn't clarify in my question, but I would like a function(or string) that I can pass to the ceil() method. So something like results.index.dt.ceil(freq='1D8H'). Or results.index.dt.ceil(freq=custom_function_offset). I should also explain I have a very long script that uses lots of ceil() calls, because so far I was mainly using general frequencies like 'H' and 'D'.

Comment: @WhiteHat - For me working `print (results.index.ceil(freq='1D8H'))`, but it seems it return wrong output. I think it is not implemented correctly.